# How to count task like completion from one column

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, count

I have a column that contains

"*********Task list completion *******
1.test
2.test
3.
4.
5.

How do I create a SQL query to count the completion? i.e. when there is text after the "number ." > 1.Test

The above would come back with count = 2

I have tried:

```
SELECT id as Task    
      ,table    
      ,table.id    
  from table             
 where table.id like '%Tier 1 Please Insure all tasks%'       
   and table.id LIKE '%3._%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT Column FROM table WHERE Column LIKE '[0-9]%._%'
) AS a
```

In where condition I checked that column:

- must start with a number
- contain a dot
- after dot at least one character

Check test output here on [DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6782cf8036676d20edba207f958958e)

---

## Update

Because you did not provide a full question at start here is my updated answer:

*Before running query I created a table with data for testing*

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (field NVARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('Test DGS ********** Tier 1 Please Insure all tasks are fully completed ********* 1.test 2.test 3. 4. 5. 6. ')

CREATE TABLE #pom (Word NVARCHAR(50))
```

I wrote main query:

```
DECLARE @Strings NVARCHAR(200) = (SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(field), charindex('*', REVERSE(field)) - 2)) FROM tbl)

WHILE LEN(@Strings) > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #pom
    SELECT LEFT(@Strings, CHARINDEX(' ', @Strings) -1) AS 'Word'

    SET @Strings = stuff(@Strings, 1, charindex(' ', @Strings + ' '), '')
END

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT Word FROM #pom WHERE Word LIKE '[0-9]%._%'
) AS a
```

And you can see output here:

[image: split string]

You can create a function or stored procedure with this code or whatever you need.

Comment: @DarrenStrong did you check db fiddle link? Please write more details about your comment.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this question, 

I have tested this and unfortunately do not get a count.   

Could you @marko-ivkovic take a look at the below please and assist?  

This is the column result - All this text is within one field =   

Test DGS  ********** Tier 1 Please Insure all tasks are fully completed *********  1.test 2.test 3. 4. 5. 6.    

SQL Querry to help clarify =         

SELECT Column
FROM table 
   WHERE table.Column like '%Tier 1 Please Insure all tasks%'

Comment: Yes this db fiddle link was useful. This shows the data being created and look up for 11 rows. This data is all within one row as a string. Could you help on this?

Comment: Then split string into more strings and implement my query logic. Trim everything before the last * character. You now have string  ` 1.test 2.test 3. 4. 5. 6.` and I suggest that use space like delimiter and continue after that normaly.

Comment: Sorry do not know how to achieve this, could you show this please? would be a great help

Comment: @DarrenStrong check update and accept the answer if that is what you want.

Comment: Hi  @marko-ivkovic Thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately, I only have access to read from this database and so cannot create the table within your solution. Is there another way of achieving this please?

Comment: @DarrenStrong try with [table variables](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-variables/). You have to be much much more creative

Comment: Hi @marko-ivkovic, Could you help guide me on this, I have looked at the link and don't know how?

Comment: Really appreciate your help on this @marko-ivkovic - This last share seems to give me this error? "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: I have added the below to now not get the error, but get count = 0 ?     case when  CHARINDEX(' ', @Strings ) = 0 then LEN(@Strings) 
else CHARINDEX(' ', @Strings) -1 end) AS 'Word'

Comment: @DarrenStrong check it [now](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bff64e57d8983398c13f02c19c5f12e4). Problem was space on end of string from table column. I added in 6 row on two place just single space. Now must works

Comment: Hi @marko-ivkovic, that has resolved that error, now I get count = 0 - I have used your example and this counts great on your test data - so is my data held differently within this column perhaps?

Comment: @DarrenStrong i really don't know what is your data from this position. I solved what you asked here on stack. On links you have my answers and adjust to your table data.

Comment: Hi @marko-ivkovic, thank you for all your help and quick responses - marked your answer as the resolution :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the data is consistently in this format, you can use wildcard expressions as below.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [table]
WHERE [column] LIKE '[1-9]%[a-z]'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this question, I have tested this and unfortunately do not get a count.   Could you @WAMLeslie take a look at the below please and assist?  This is the column result =   Test DGS  ********** Tier 1 Please Insure all tasks are fully completed *********  1.test 2.test 3. 4. 5. 6.

Comment: @DarrenStrong I've updated my query above to include a `COUNT()`.  You will need to change my `[table]` and `[column]` to correspond to whatever your actual table and column names are.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this question, I have tested this and unfortunately do not get a count. Could you @marko-ivkovic take a look at the below please and assist? This is the column result - All this text is within one field = Test DGS ********** Tier 1 Please Insure all tasks are fully completed ********* 1.test 2.test 3. 4. 5. 6. SQL Querry to help clarify = SELECT Column FROM table WHERE table.Column like '%Tier 1 Please Insure all tasks%'     This data is all within one row as a string. Could you help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table
WHERE table.id LIKE '[1-9]%[a-z]'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this question, I have tested this and unfortunately do not get a count.   Could you @alexander-chef take a look at the below please and assist?  This is the column result =   Test DGS  ********** Tier 1 Please Insure all tasks are fully completed *********  1.test 2.test 3. 4. 5. 6.

Comment: Hi Darren, you can check it from dbfiddle link. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3a41349fef02907b27c5849540940b2. Maybe the problem is your SQL platform. Which SQL are you using? Mysql, MSSQL or which one?

Comment: Hi @alexander-chef, This dbfiddle shows the data being created and look up for 5 rows. This data is all within one row as a string. The other issue is that I have no write access to the db and so cannot use a SQL SP etc. Could you help?